# How to enable a dropdownlist in an update panel to make a full post back

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, postback

Q:

I have the following case :

Two drop down lists :

- The first one for the camp.
- The second one for the faculty .

When the user selects from the camp .I fill the faculty ddl according to his selection.

I put my second ddl in an updatepanel so ,this part of the page only posted back.

but i wanna when i select an item from the second ddl(the faculty one), force full post back to the whole page to view an report .

How to do this .

**My aspx:**

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_camp_s" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_camp_s_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

---

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_fac_s" runat="server" Width="400px" AutoPostBack="True"
                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_fac_s_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_camp_s" 
                                        EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: by design if you put it inside the update panel you will have the partial rendering, if you want that drop down to trigger a full page post back take it out of the UpdatePanel. There might be some hacky solutions but the concept is wrong, if it has to trigger a full post back it should not be places inside the update panel!

Comment: How about writing Bind() function in second ddls SelectedIndexChanged to update the page

Comment: hmmm, when select from the first one ,i want just render the second ddl,so i put it in an update panel, but later i find that i wanna when selecting from the second one make a full post back.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better using cascadingdropdown from ajax control toolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in your update panel triggers

```
 <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ControlIdToForceFullPOstBack" />
 </Triggers>
```

Hope this help